# Inner Product Additivity Rules

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

Do inner products show additivity in the first slot or second slot or both?
In other words, which of the following is/are true?

$$\langle u,v+w\rangle = \langle u,v\rangle + \langle u,w\rangle$$
    $$\langle u+v,w\rangle = \langle u,w\rangle + \langle v,w\rangle$$
   $$ \langle u+v,w+x\rangle = \langle u,w\rangle + \langle u,x\rangle + \langle v,w\rangle + \langle v,x\rangle$$

$v,w,x,y \in$ Vector space $(V,F)$, $F = \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Welcome to Math SX! They're all true. An inner product is linear in each variable.

Comment: An inner product ist not linear in the second variable if $F= \mathbb C$ !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that inner products have the properties positive-definiteness, **linearity in the first argument** and **conjugate symmetry**, so it is indeed true that you always have
$$\langle u+v,w\rangle = \langle u,w\rangle + \langle v,w\rangle$$
and
$$\langle u,v+w\rangle = \overline{\langle v+w,u\rangle}=\overline{\langle v,u\rangle + \langle w,u\rangle}=\overline{\langle v,u\rangle} + \overline{\langle w,u\rangle}=\langle u,v\rangle + \langle u,w\rangle$$
and therefore also
$$\langle u+v,w+x\rangle = \langle u,w+x\rangle + \langle v,w+x\rangle = \langle u,w\rangle + \langle u,x\rangle + \langle v,w\rangle + \langle v,x\rangle$$
for both $F=\mathbb{R}$ and $F=\mathbb{C}$.